# why the second row td is the same width with the first one

Tags: html, css

```
<table  width="980" border="0">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td width="25%">
                <img width="300"  style="overflow: hidden;" alt="" src="1.jpg">
            </td>
            <td width="75%">
                <h1>ttt</h1>
                <p>dgggg</p>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td width="25%"><img  alt="" src="98.jpg"></td>
            <td width="25%"><img  alt="" src="57_998.jpg"></td>
            <td width="25%"><img  alt="" src="7_998.jpg"></td>
            <td width="25%"><img alt="" src="98.jpg"></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Why is the second row td the same width with the first one(the first row td). the width="25%" doesn't work. how to correct it?

Comment: The width of each column in a table will always be the same. You can't have two rows with different column widths inside of them. For instance, if you want row 1 column 1's width to be different than row 2 column 1's width, you must put them in a different table.

Comment: "you must put them in a different table" this is not true http://jsbin.com/egahey

Comment: Also, 25% of 980 is 245, but your image in the first cell has a width of 300 will probably prevent the table from formatting as expected.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use `colspan` attribute to achieve this

```
<table  width="980" border="0">
<tbody>
<tr>
    <td width="25%"><h1>A</h1></td>
    <td width="75%" colspan="3"><h1>B</h1></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td width="25%">1</td>
    <td width="25%">2</td>
    <td width="25%">3</td>
    <td width="25%">4</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

A good intro on the `colspan` attribute can be found here: http://reference.sitepoint.com/html/td/colspan

Here's a quick example similar to what you tried to achieve
http://jsbin.com/egahey/1/

Answer (score 1):

**by default** in html, the column in a row takes the inherited width of the column in the preceding row ,
 for achieving desired you have to use **col span**.

```
           <table  width="980" border="0">
           <tbody>
                 <tr>
                   <td width="25%"><img width="300"  src="1.jpg"></td>
                   <td width="75%" colspan="3"><h1>ttt</h1><p>dgggg</p></td>
                 </tr>

                 <tr>
                   <td width="25%"><img alt="" src="98.jpg"></td>
                   <td width="25%"><img alt="" src="57_998.jpg"></td>
                   <td width="25%"><img alt="" src="7_998.jpg"></td>
                   <td width="25%"><img alt="" src="98.jpg"></td>
                </tr>
          </tbody>
     </table>
```

Answer (score -2):

Imagine a table as an excel worksheet. All the rows in the same column must be the same width (of course, you can combine them just like excel too).
As for your question, you need to split the table into 2 tables to achieve different width:

```
<table  width="980" border="0">
<tbody>
<tr>
    <td width="25%"><img width="300"  style="overflow: hidden;" alt="" src="1.jpg"></td>
    <td width="75%"><h1>ttt</h1><p>dgggg</p></td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>

<table  width="980" border="0">
<tbody>
<tr>
    <td width="25%"><img  alt="" src="98.jpg"></td>
    <td width="25%"><img  alt="" src="57_998.jpg"></td>
    <td width="25%"><img  alt="" src="7_998.jpg"></td>
    <td width="25%"><img alt="" src="98.jpg"></td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```